# Glassfish + CDI results in IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, cdi

Trying my hand at CDI for the first time. I'm using Glassfish v3. When I deploy my app, I get the following failure:

> java.io.IOException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.remote.RemoteFailureException:
>   Exception while loading the app :
>   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException:
>   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
>   com.example.arizona.client.ArizonaService
>   and
>   com.example.arizona.client.ArizonaService$App
>   disagree on InnerClasses attribute
>
> at
>   com.fuhrer.idea.glassfish.server.GlassfishServer3.doParseResponse(GlassfishServer3.java:28)
>     at
>   com.fuhrer.idea.glassfish.server.GlassfishServer3Base.parseResponse(GlassfishServer3Base.java:156)
>     at
>   com.fuhrer.idea.glassfish.server.GlassfishServer3Base.invoke(GlassfishServer3Base.java:127)
>     at
>   com.fuhrer.idea.glassfish.server.GlassfishServer3Base.handleDeployment(GlassfishServer3Base.java:78)
>     at
>   com.fuhrer.idea.javaee.server.JavaeeServerInstance$2.run(JavaeeServerInstance.java:131)

I should mention that I'm not even actually *using* injection, or any other CDI features yet. This is just trying to get the dependencies straightened out.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, but with Weld in Tomcat. Problem for me was caused by changing an inner class definition to a normal class. Resulted, in my case, in having the old innerclass still in the classes directory but with a new parent class.

Cleaning the classes directory worked for me.

Comment: A bit late I see, ah well, maybe it'll help somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

Nearly a year later I'm sorry to say that I never solved this, and for various reasons moved on to another stack altogether: Tomcat, Wicket and [Wicket-CDI](https://github.com/42Lines/wicket-cdi), all of which have worked great for me.